# what does typecasting actually means in java?

Tags: java, object, interface

Does it change one object to another? if `Imonitor` is an interface what does `Imonitor[] x = new Imonitor();` means? Does that mean we can create objects of interfaces?

Comment: You cannot directly instantiate an interface.

Answer (score 3):

Well, casting does different things depending on what types you're talking about. Consider:

```
Object x = "hello";
String y = (String) x;
```

That isn't changing the type of the *object* - but it's converting a *reference* of type `Object` to a *reference* of type `String`, by checking that the reference either refers to a `String` (or, more generally, the target type of the cast or a subclass) or to null.

For primitive types, it actually *does* create a new data value of a different type, changing the *information* copied rather than just changing a reference to the information:

```
double x = 10.5;
int y = (int) x; // The value of y is 10; x is unchanged though.
```

---

Regarding interfaces:

```
Imonitor[] x = new Imonitor();
```

This won't compile directly. But this will:

```
Imonitor[] x = new Imonitor[2];
```

This isn't creating any instances of `Imonitor` itself - it's just creating an *array* with two "slots" capable of holding references to objects of types implementing of `Imonitor`. The initial value in both those slots will be `null`; you might then populate the array like this:

```
x[0] = new FirstImplementation();
x[1] = new SecondImplemnentation();
```

... creating instances of concrete implementation classes.

Answer (score 1):

> > Does it change one object to another?

(1) No. For reference types

```
a = (typename)b;
```

informs the compiler that you "know" that the object which 'b' points to is also an object of type 'typename'. That is, it is an operator over references rather than object. (For primitive types, it is actually a conversion).

> > if Imonitor is an interface what does Imonitor[] x = new Imonitor(); means?

(2) It won't compile. Imonitor is a type name. Imonitor[] is an array of IMonitors.

> > Does that mean we can create objects of interfaces?

(3) No. But you can create an array of references to Imonitor, which is what

```
new IMonitor[3]
```

would do.

Comment: Consider expanding on the different topics.

Answer (score 1):

if `Imonitor` is an interface, than `new Imonitor();` doesn't work.

`Imonitor[] x` is an `Imonitor`-array not a `Imonitor` variable.

Answer (score 1):

new Imonitor() will  not work if Imonitor is an interface - you will get a compilation error.

To cast an object is to change the type that the compiler think the object has (the static type) and does checks against. When the program is being run, then the JavaVm checks that the cast is valid, if not an exception is thrown.

Interfaces can never be objects, you must have a class that implements the interface for that.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said (and I did in my comment) you cannot directly instantiate an interface.  I suggest you read up on Java interfaces to become more familiar with them - they can be confusing at first but they're a critical part of the language.

[Here is the section](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) on interfaces at the Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting is also known as [type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion), it is to change an object from one data type to another. In non-primitive objects, typecasting is done on objects which have certain features of hierarchies. Example: A `Person` object has 2 subclasses called `Parent` and `Child` (both subclasses have the same hierchical structure as they inherit `Person`), therefore this is a valid type conversion:

```
Person person = new Parent();
Parent parent = (Parent) person;
```

For your example, `Imonitor[] x = new Imonitor();` will not compile as you are assigning a single objet of `Imonitor` to an instance that **expects** an array of `Imonitor`.

But this would compile:

```
Imonitor[] x = new Imonitor[2]; //Assigning 2 elements to array 'x'
```

Suppose that you have an interface:

```
public interface IMonitor {

    public void monitor(Monitorable object) throws MonitorException;
}
```

Then this wouldn't be a type casting example, but an assignment:

```
IMonitor x = new IMonitor() {
            public void monitor(Monitorable object) throws MonitorException {
                //Implementation done here...
            }
        };
```

(The above example demonstrate [anonymous class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class#Types_of_inner_classes)).

I hope this is clear.